# catplot in sns showing intersections which are actually not there

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to create a catplot in sns and the sample data is below
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Lq3KH6Mj1WVPNA4ByJwtFQd4ovLd4lgi/view?usp=sharing

when I use the below to generate the plot

```
fig=sns.catplot(data=df, x = 'SubCategory', hue='filedate',col='Category',kind='count')
```

I get the below plot.

[image]

Why does the SubCategory like "G" come in Category 1 and 2 when it is only in 3. Also how can I just bring those SubCategories which are in respective Category instead of all SubCategories showing up against all the Categories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think it's possible to drop the categories with count = 0, you can try to define a custom function and call FacetGrid , which catplot uses:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv("./Downloads/zrr2weeks.csv")

def bplot(x,y,**kwargs):
    sns.countplot(x,hue=y,**kwargs)
g = sns.FacetGrid(df,col='Category',sharex=False)
g.map(bplot,'SubCategory','filedate')
```

[image]

You can see in Category 8 there are two Gs which are "G" and "G ". Not very sure if this is intended. If not:

```
df.SubCategory = df.SubCategory.str.replace(" ","")
g = sns.FacetGrid(df,col='Category',sharex=False)
g.map(bplot,'SubCategory','filedate')
```

[image]

Comment: When I run the above code in Jupiter it creates only one Figure with the plot but when I run the below code in PyCharm it creates 2 Figures with one being empty and the other with data, Can you please explain why. I am also trying to digest the above code as new to Python. plt.figure()      def bplot(x,y,**kwargs):
    sns.countplot(x,hue=y)
g = sns.FacetGrid(zrr2weeks,col='SBU',sharex=False, col_wrap=2)
g.map(bplot,'CostCenter','filedate')

Comment: Hi @Sunil, sorry I don't use PyCharm. If you need to get this to work in pycharm, consider posting it as a separate question

Comment: hi @StupidWolf . Really appreciate your time to respond back. I was able to solve it by removing plt.figure() and then it would just create one figure. Thanks for your support and help